# IOS set error message in string to show in alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

i have looked for a simple solution for my problem but i couldn't find any simple one.
From server i receive some messages which are strings like this :

> "error": {
>           "message": "Incorrect email and/or password"
>       }

or this :

> "error": {
>           "message": "You need to complete all fields"
>       }

Each time for each call from server it will return different message.

In my alert view i need to show message part only like : **Incorrect email and or password**.

I tried this codes :

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
NSString *errorString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
NSArray* foo = [errorString componentsSeparatedByString: @"message"];NSString* day = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];
NSCharacterSet *trim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\/:{}"];
NSString *result = [[day componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:trim] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

But the problem is its not dynamic,
How can i get message part of this strings and remove all special characters inside them and set them into another string to show them in an alert dynamically ?

[image: this is a image of what i have in my dictionary]

Comment: What exactly are you receiving from the server? That looks like JSON to me, or at least it *should* be JSON. Is it your server, can you change the received message?

Comment: its an response error that i receive from server inside a nserror.userInfo

Comment: I doubt you are doing the correct thing here, show some more code, where does the log you show come from? Where does the `error` come from?

Comment: what you posted is a dictionary .. why do you do string manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're getting NSString from the server? Can you try this string?

```
NSString *errorMessage = userInfo[@"error"][@"message"];
```

**UPD1:**
If after the first string of your code you've got `{ "error": { "message": "Incorrect email and/or password"} }` in errorMessage do the next:

```
    NSString *errorString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
    NSError *err = nil;
    //Here will be your message and other
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[errorString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    NSString *message = dict[@"error"][@"message"];
```

But to be sure show what exactly do you have in userInfo dictionary (make screenshot of it at a breakpoint) and in errorString after

```
NSString *errorString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
```

Comment: Yeah , im sure its a NSString.

Comment: @Sattar Great. So use my code from upd1. And NSString *message = dict[@"error"][@"message"]; will be your message.

Comment: Thanks that work perfectly ... can you explain it how exactly it works ?

Comment: @Sattar There's json in userInfo[@"error"] but it's represented as a string. [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: options:error:] returns id object that represents given data in JSON format that we cast to NSDictionary(we know it's a dictionary from string syntax). Our string we  represent as data in UTF-8 format. 
[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:)

Comment: Thanks , I understand it now :)